# Android not executing intent in for loop

Tags: android, json, android-intent

I'm pulling some JSON responses and depending on wether or not there is a certain object in the response, I want to go to one activity or the other. However, even though my condition for checking id the JSON object is in there works, it is not going to the activity in the `if` statement. Why is my activity not terminating once it reaches the `startActivity` in the `if` statement?

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                JSONObject passingObject = modelsObjectList.get(position);
                ArrayList<String> nextPlacesList = new ArrayList<>();

                try {


                    if(passingObject.optJSONArray("places") == null){
                        Log.v("WE ARE IN THE LOOP", "in the loop");
                        name = passingObject.getString("name");
                        id = passingObject.getLong("id");
                        Log.d("NEXT ACTIVITY NAME", name);
                        System.out.println("NEXT ACTIVITY ID " + id);
                        Log.d("NEXT SERIES LIST", nextPlacesList.toString());

                        Intent intent = new Intent(SeriesActivity.this, SecondSeriesActivity.class);
                        intent.putExtra("id", id);
                        intent.putExtra("name", name);
                        intent.putExtra("placesList", nextPlacesList);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }

                    Log.v("SHOULDN'T BE HERE", "this is bad");
                    JSONArray places = passingObject.getJSONArray("places");
                    for(int i = 0; i < places.length(); i++){
                        nextPlacesList.add(places.getString(i));

                    }

                    name = passingObject.getString("name");
                    id = passingObject.getLong("id");
                    Log.d("NEXT ACTIVITY NAME", name);
                    System.out.println("NEXT ACTIVITY ID " + id);
                    Log.d("NEXT SERIES LIST", nextPlacesList.toString());

                } catch(JSONException e){
                    Log.d("JSONEXCEPTION", e.getMessage());
                }

                Intent intent = new Intent(SeriesActivity.this, PlacesListActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("id", id);
                intent.putExtra("name", name);
                intent.putExtra("placesList", nextPlacesList);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
}
```

Comment: would calling finish() help ?

Comment: java 101: A function executes until it reaches one of 3 things: an exception, a return statement, the end of the function block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`startActivity` doesn't stop the execution of the method. You need to have `return` before the end of the `if` block to prevent it from continuing to the `SHOULDNT BE HERE` section.